# Adding Items to DataGridView from a ListBox to a Single Column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

I need to populate a DataGridView with items from a List.

I need the first row of the GridView populated with the items from the String List and i need to do some processing on the items in the GridView one by one and add the result to the second row(String).

Currently im Binding the DataGridView like this

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = mylist.ConvertAll(x => new { Value = x });
 dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

I need to predefine the column name add strings in the first row,process these strings one by one and update the second column..what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

here is your solution,

```
        dgvDataViewer.ColumnCount = 1;
        dgvDataViewer.Columns[0].Name = "Language";

        string[] row = new string[] { "C#" };
        dgvDataViewer.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "C++" };
        dgvDataViewer.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "C" };
        dgvDataViewer.Rows.Add(row);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cmb.HeaderText = "HeaderText";
        cmb.Name = "Name";
        cmb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
        dgvDataViewer.Columns.Add(cmb);

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcbc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvDataViewer.Rows[0].Cells[1];
        dgvcbc.Items.Add("Apple");
        dgvcbc.Items.Add("Google");
        dgvcbc.Items.Add("Apache");
        dgvcbc.Items.Add("Microsoft");
```

Hope this will help you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to build your columns either programmatically or you can use the designer - that is up to you.  I will code all of it for the sake of showing the entire example:

```
private DataGridView dgNew;

public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyInitializeComponent();
}

private void MyInitializeComponent()
{
    dgNew = new DataGridView();

    var txtCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "Column1",
        Name = "Column1",
        DataPropertyName = "Value"
    };
    dgNew.Columns.Add(txtCol);

    txtCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "Column2",
        Name = "Column2",
    };
    dgNew.Columns.Add(txtCol);

    var listOfStrings = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};
    dgNew.DataSource = listOfStrings.ConvertAll(x => new { Value = x }); ;
    dgNew.Location = dg.Location;
    dgNew.Parent = this;

    this.Load += Form_Load;
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Iterate over the rows, ignoring the header row
    foreach (var row in dgNew.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(a => a.Index != -1))
    {
        var col1Value = row.Cells["Column1"].Value?.ToString();
        var col2Cell = row.Cells["Column2"];

        if (col1Value == null) continue;

        switch (col1Value)
        {
            case ("one"):
                col2Cell.Value = "row1, col2 val";
                break;
            case ("two"):
                col2Cell.Value = "row2, col2 val";
                break;
            case ("three"):
                col2Cell.Value = "row1, col3 val";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```